# React-router как правильно сделать переход на карточку из каталога

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Первые попытки в реакт и сразу затык на теме, из-за которой реакт и интересен был.. До Redux еще далеко, поэтому пытаюсь решить задачу только силами реакта. Нужно сделать каталог и по превью из каталога переходить на страницу с детальной информацией. Каталог рендерится из обычного массива с объектами:

```
import { mashines } from '../../assets/mashines.js';
    function CatalogPreview() {
        return (
            <div className="preview_container">
                {mashines.map((obj) => (
                    <MashinesCoverage 
                    key={obj.id}
                    {...obj} />
                )
                )}; 
            </div>)}
```

В блоке function MashinesCoverage({article, imgUrl}) {

```
    return (
    <div className="products-card-coverage">
             <NavLink 
                to={`/catalog/${article}`}
                className="card-link"
                 >
                <img 
               className="preview-img"
               src={imgUrl}
               alt={article}
               />
</div>
```

В App прописаны роуты:

```
<Router>
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/catalog" component={Catalog} />
        <Route path="/catalog/:id" render={() => <ProductCard/>}/>
        <Route path="/servise" component={Servise} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Каталог отображается, при клике на картинку адрес URL меняется. Как теперь сделать, чтобы при клике открывалась детальная информация? Детальная информация находится в том же массиве.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код вашего примера. Я создал компонент `<ProductCard/>` который из `props.match` берет `id` из `URL`. Далее при наличии исходного массива (можно импортировать если это отдельный файл) можно найти необходимый элемент массива для отображения. Чаще конечно должен быть дополнительный запрос на сервер в `useEffect`. Если есть вопросы задавайте в комментах.

```
 import React from "react";
 import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
 
 const machines = [
   { id: 1, label: "Machine1", description: "Description1" },
   { id: 2, label: "Machine2", description: "Description2" },
   { id: 3, label: "Machine3", description: "Description3" },
   { id: 4, label: "Machine4", description: "Description4" },
 ];
 
 const App = () => {
   return (
     <BrowserRouter>
       <NavLink to="/catalog">Catalog</NavLink>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/catalog" exact={true} component={CatalogPreview} />
         <Route path="/catalog/:id" component={ProductCard} />
       </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
   );
 };
 
 const CatalogPreview = () => {
   return (
     <div className="preview_container">
       <h2>Catalog:</h2>
       {machines.map((item) => (
         <MashinesCoverage key={item.id} {...item} />
       ))}
     </div>
   );
 };
 
 const MashinesCoverage = ({ label, id }) => {
   return (
     <div className="products-card-coverage">
       <NavLink to={`/catalog/${id}`} className="card-link">
         Link to {label}
       </NavLink>
     </div>
   );
 };
 
 const ProductCard = ({ match }) => {
   const id = Number(match.params.id);
   const cardToShow = machines.find((item) => item.id === id);
   return (
     <div>
       <h2>ProductCard:</h2>
       <h3>Label: {cardToShow.label}</h3>
       <h3>Description: {cardToShow.description}</h3>
       <h3>ID: {cardToShow.id}</h3>
     </div>
   );
 };
 
 export default App;
```

Comment: Спасибо, код действительно рабочий! Но когда я разношу все по компонентам и импортирую массив "mashines" из его файла на этапе MashinesCoverage все работает отлично, а в ProductCard выдает ошибку 'machines' is not defined. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Значит файл не правилно импортирован, возможно опечатка. Нужно проверить чтобы везде имя было правилно написано.

Comment: Да, глаз замылился.. Теперь ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property, вывожу в консоль id NaN, cardToShow undefined

Comment: Ошибка возникает тут: `const id = Number(match.params.id);` не может преобразовать в число, все `id` числа ?

Comment: Нет, уже внутри дива, <h3>ID: {cardToShow.id}</h3>  - ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined, на константы не ругается

Comment: id NaN следовательно не может найти элемент в массиве, cardToShow === undefined