# Перерисовка компонента при нажатии на элемент li

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, jsx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перерисовать имеющийся компонент на react jsx при нажатии на элемент li. Имеется компонент **Content**. Он отрисовывает список с карточками треков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
export default function Content() {
 // Содержимое компонента.

    function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    return (
                <main className="content">
                    <h2 className="title_content">Новые Релизы</h2>
                    <ul className="content-releases">
                        {items.map(
                            (item) => (
                                <li className="releases-container" key={item.id} onClick={onClick}>
                                    <img src={item.images[1].url} alt="releases_image" width="150" height="150" />
                                    <span className="name-track">{item.name}</span>
                                    <span className="name-artist">{item.artists[0].name}</span>
                                </li>
                            )
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </main>
            );

}
```

После нажатия на элемент li нужно, чтобы рендер выглядел так (изменены классы css, текст, разметка и т.д)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовать? Пробовала просто в функцию **onClick** прописать нужный рендер, но не работает. Я только начинаю изучение React. Компоненты пишу не классами

Comment: Гляньте в сторону роутинга. При клике на альбом вас должно перенести на url вида site.com/albums/423523/

Comment: спасибо, сейчас почитаю про это

Comment: Вот, кстати, похожий вопрос с [решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238183/react-router-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Да, это именно то, что мне нужно, ещё раз спасибо большое!